# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin error in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to connect hibernate with my application but i am getting exceptions which is after many attempts also i am unable to sort it out. Below is my complete stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at com.sample.pack1.MunimCustBillingUI.main(MunimCustBillingUI.java:121)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:37)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
... 14 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@Akash-VAIO:1521:XE
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:34)
... 24 more
```

Below are my hibernate.cfg.xml file configurations:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver.class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@Akash-VAIO:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hr</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">hr</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>

        <mapping class="Employees.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

And following are my java class codes:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employees e = new Employees();
    e.setFirst_name("Akash");
    e.setLast_name("Narayan");
    e.setEmail("xyq@gmail.com");
    e.setHire_date(new Date());
    e.setJob_id("IT_PROG");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(e);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

My db is Oracle 10.2.0 and i have following jars in my classpath :  `antlr-2.7.7, dom4j-16.1, geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1, hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.0, hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final, hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final, jandex-1.2.2.Final, javassist-3.18.1, jboss-logging-3.30.Final, ojdbc14_g`

Any suggestions ?

Comment: "No suitable driver" means  the driver isn't loaded at all.

Comment: yep, still pondering over, what have i done driver to not load.

Comment: Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

Comment: @j0d0 done that..still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an old JDBC driver. With package `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`, as @j0d0 said you. To use the package `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` you need a new driver, for an example `ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar`.

And, please, don't use `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect`. It is deprecated. Use `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` instead.

Comment: What i still dint got is even the **ojdbc14.jar** has `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.class` inside apparently, but it failed even. It only worked when i changed the jar and the dialect as suggested. Please enlighten me..

Comment: bdw tnq vry mch, u've made my day:)

Comment: @Akash You are welcome :) Yeah, you are right with oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.class. But I can't explain it.